# MYSQL subquery count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a q MySQL query that finds  part numbers and returns the count; I need to figure out how to get the query to output by part number counts

this my query now

```
 select count(partnumber)
 from db1
 where part number REGEXP '6270|6269|6266'
```

output part number 30

what I would like is the output to look like this,

```
part numbers count 
6270      | 20
6269       | 10
6266      | 5
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is a better way to write the query:

```
 select partnumber, count(*)
 from db1 where partnumber in (6270, 6269, 6266)
 group by partnumber;
```

This `in` expression is not exactly the same as your regular expression (the equivalent regular expression would be `'^6270|6269|6266$'`).  If you really want partial matches, then you should use the regular expression.

For exact matches, `in` is better because (1) it is standard SQL; (2) the types are correct in the comparison; and (3) it optimizes better.